# Testing PHP method that depends on another method

Tags: php, unit-testing

Unsure of the best way to unit test this:

```
<?php

class Test
{
    public static function random(){
        return rand(0,9);
    }

    public static function nonDuplicateRandom($dupes){
        $rand = self::random();
        while(in_array($rand, $dupes)){
            $rand = self::random();
        }
        return $rand;
    }
}

echo Test::nonDuplicateRandom(array(0,1,2,3,4,5));
```

Should I modify `nonDuplicateRandom` so it can be passed a `$rand` value to test against or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you talking about PHPUnit here? This is where you would *mock* the `random()` method and tell it what it's going to return, since maybe you don't want to test its functionality when calling the `nonDuplicateRandom` method. However, in this particular example you could test the functionality of both methods by calling that one because they are both (A) tiny and (B) NDR is dependent on `random` working correctly, so you can annotate `@covers` in your PHPDoc block and reference both methods from your test

Comment: Yes PHPUnit. Right get you, that makes perfect sense. If I WERE to mock `random()` how would I go about doing that given the current code?

Comment: The problem is that if you mock the function you need to define its return value, and in this case the return value is totally crucial to the logic of `nonDuplicateRandom`. If I were you I'd just test `nonDuplicateRandom` and assume that `random()` is part of its functionality. It also shouldn't be public, maybe make it protected instead.